# how to remove the duplicates in sql

Tags: sql

How can I remove duplicate results in the following sql?

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      fccestimatedcustomer LEFT JOIN fcccustomerregistration 
ON        fccestimatedcustomer.CustomerRegistrationRefID = 
          fcccustomerregistration.CustomerRegistrationRefID
WHERE     fccestimatedcustomer.Status = 1 
ORDER BY  VehicleNumber ASC;
```

Comment: google `distinct`.

Comment: please show us your current result & tell us on which you want to remove duplication

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM      fccestimatedcustomer LEFT JOIN fcccustomerregistration 
ON        fccestimatedcustomer.CustomerRegistrationRefID = 
          fcccustomerregistration.CustomerRegistrationRefID
WHERE     fccestimatedcustomer.Status = 1 
ORDER BY  VehicleNumber ASC;
```

Try this.If not works, post some example data of your fccestimatedcustomer , fcccustomerregistration tables

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `DISTINCT` with specified field on which you would like to do this selection.